# Using React Dev Tools with Chrome Extension based on manifest v3

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3, react-devtools

I am developing a Chrome Extension based on manifest v3 and can't get React dev tools to work.

Here is what I did:

1. `yarn add -D react-devtools`
2. Add script tag to page of extension:

```
  <script src="http://localhost:8097"></script>
```

3. Add content security policy to the manifest file:

```
 "content_security_policy": {
    "extension_pages": "script-src 'self'; object-src 'self'; script-src-elem 'self'; unsafe-inline 'localhost';"
}
```

Error I am getting:

```
Refused to load the script 'http://localhost:8097/' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src-elem 'self'".
```

I have tried all kinds of variations in `unsafe-inline` and nothing seems to work.

Comment: Your script-src-elem is invalid. Try `script-src-elem 'self' 'unsafe-inline' http://localhost`